# How do I add a new data attribute to an existing html element or div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I wanted to figure out if it is possible to add a new data attribute to an existing html element. So for instance:

```
<button class="confirm-button" data-id=560>Click Me</button>
```

I will like to be able to add a new data attribute using jquery like

```
<button class="confirm-button" data-text="justaddedattr" data-id=560>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: [setAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Comment: Did you try anything?  `$(".confirm-button).attr("data-id","560")` `$(".confirm-button).data("id","560")` (last with caveats that are explained in *numerous* SO posts)

Comment: You want to add it manually or with `js` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with jQuery's [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$('.confirm-button').attr('data-text', 'justaddedattr');
console.log($('.confirm-button').data('text'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="confirm-button" data-id=560>Click Me</button>
```

You can also try [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$('.confirm-button').data('text', 'justaddedattr');
console.log($('.confirm-button').data('text'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="confirm-button" data-id=560>Click Me</button>
```